# Why doesn't this code solve LeetCode Problem 74 "Search a 2d Matrix"

Tags: rust

The Problem is [here](https://leetcode.com/problems/search-a-2d-matrix/). I didn't define my algorithm recursively. I get the time limit exceeded error for the very first example:

```
input: [[1,3,5,7],[10,11,16,20],[23,30,34,60]]
target: 3
```

But running this code on paper, it really seems like it terminates properly (to me at least).

```
use std::cmp::Ordering;
use std::cmp;

impl Solution {
    pub fn search_matrix(matrix: Vec<Vec<i32>>, target: i32) -> bool {
        let m       = matrix.len();
        let n       = matrix[0].len();
        let mut min = 0; 
        let mut max = n * m - 1;
        while  min != max {
            let mid = (min + max) / 2;
            match target.cmp(&matrix[mid / n][mid % n]) {
                Ordering::Less    => max = cmp::max(0    ,mid - 1),
                Ordering::Equal   => return true,
                Ordering::Greater => min = cmp::min(n*m-1,mid + 1),
            }
        }
        return target == matrix[min / n][min % n];
    }
}
```

I thought maybe the problem was the matrix indexing, but I tried every permutation (`[mid / m][mid % m]`, `[mid / n][mid % m]`, and so on) to no avail. The mins and maxes are also relatively new in the hopes of ensuring I don't go out of bounds.

Comment: If you have the failing input, then you can create a [mre], with the input hard-coded into the program, to build and [debug](https://ericlippert.com/2014/03/05/how-to-debug-small-programs/) locally on your own system.

Comment: Also note that so-called "competition" sites usually expects very specific algorithms using very specific implementations, and set their timings according to that. One mistake, or picking a suitable but different algorithm, and your program will not be accepted. Those sites aren't for learning programming, languages, or generic algorithms, but for figuring out the specific "trick" needed for each question.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are cases where the condition `min != max` can never be satisfied. (Consider `min = 0` and `max = 1`.)

A standard binary search uses `min <= max` as the loop condition. The final thing to watch out for is that `mid - 1` could produce `-1`, which would overflow with `usize`. To rectify this, we could set the bounds of the search as going from `1` to `n * m`, and subtract one from `mid` when accessing the element.

```rust
pub fn search_matrix(matrix: Vec<Vec<i32>>, target: i32) -> bool {
    let m = matrix.len();
    let n = matrix[0].len();
    let mut min = 1;
    let mut max = n * m;
    while min <= max {
        let mid = (min + max) / 2;
        match target.cmp(&matrix[(mid - 1) / n][(mid - 1) % n]) {
            Ordering::Less => max = mid - 1,
            Ordering::Equal => return true,
            Ordering::Greater => min = mid + 1,
        }
    }
    return false;
}
```

Also, since the bounds on `n` and `m` are so small, brute force easily passes:

```rust
pub fn search_matrix(matrix: Vec<Vec<i32>>, target: i32) -> bool {
    for r in matrix {
        for x in r {
            if x == target {
                return true
            }
        }
    }
    false
}
```

Comment: Hey, first of all thank you so much for your help!